# programmatically click on a HTML button in WebView from fragment in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, webview

I need to open a dialog in a website which opens on clicking a HTML button of the website. I'm trying to click on a HTML button based on the id from the fragment, how can I perform the action, I'm using

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                
        // trying to click the button with id btn-to-be-clicked
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('btn-to-be-clicked').click();})()");
            }
}
```

thanks

I tried
`webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('btn-to-be-clicked').click();})()");`

Answer (score 0):

so apparently you must specify every line in a new string

extracted the js to a variable with multi line, it has to be a multi line concatenated string

```
val jsFunction = "javascript:(function() { " +
                "document.getElementById('btn-to-be-clicked').click();" +
                "})()"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `onPageFinished()` method, run the script calling the `view.loadUrl()` method or `view.evaluateJavascript()`, as you can see in the below example:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    // 1st method
    view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                 "document.getElementById('btn-to-be-clicked').click();" +
                 "})()");

    // 2nd method
    view.evaluateJavascript(
                 "javascript:(function() { " +
                 "document.getElementById('btn-to-be-clicked').click();" +
                 "})()", new ValueCallback<String>() {
           @Override
           public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
                // You could use this callback method to do something
                // after the click was executed.
           }
    });
}
```